# Initializing Magellan threshold + Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

If I understand correctly, putting $(document).foundation('magellan', { threshold: 500 }) in the right place in my html will cause Magellan (a sticky nav bar in Foundation) to not jump to the sticky position it's scrolled 500 pixels down from the top.

I have no idea why it is not working. This is what I have at the moment at the bottom of my page, just before the body tage.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<script>
  $(document).foundation('magellan', { threshold: 500 })
</script>
```

IT DOES NOT WORK. It jumps to the top corner and stays there. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I asked about this on the issues page on GitHub.  This appears to be a bug.  If the Zurb team doesn't get around to it by the time I need to launch I'll have to figure it out.